# Calling Put method in Web API with asp.net MVC as client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have created a Web-api with following put method

public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody]DataModel model)

in the put method i pass the object and it get updated in the database. Its working i have checked it with fiddler.

Now in My MVC Application i call it using the following code

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult OrderSearch(DataModel model)
    {
        UpdateOrder(model).Wait();
        if (putresult != null && putresult != string.Empty)
        {
            return Json(putresult);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("Error in getting result");
        }
    }

    private async Task UpdateOrder(DataModel model)
    {
       string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
       {
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


           HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsync("api/values/"+ model.OrderNo,new StringContent(json)).Result;

           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               putresult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();

           }
       }

    }
```

But the code does not hit my Put method on the service and putresult remains blank. I try to search about PutAsync usage but could not find anything so please help.

Comment: You are doing a put to a post method?

Comment: Well OrderSearch is a partial view when user edit the information he wants he click the submit button and it post the data, now since data is not new it has been already available so i am using put to update the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Using .Wait in any ASP.NET runtime application is likely to result in a deadlock.  I'm not sure how you are supposed to handle async methods in MVC.

Comment: yes if someone handle by being careless. but in my case the above client is calling the api my get and get(int) are getting called and returning proper values, but put (signature given in the question) is not getting called.